# How to check if a given IP @ is a subnet @ address?

Tags: ip, subnet

Is there a way to check if a given IP address is a subnet IP address ?
For example :
16.100.134.0 /19
this IP address is a subnet ip address (I saw it in the solution ) but I still don't know how they figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

The /19 at the end tells you that this is a subnet address.

A complete IPV4 address is 4 lots of 8 bits or octets (each shown as a decimal in the range 0 -255) so 32 bits long. /19 tells you that this is the address of a subnet where the first 19 bits are reserved for the network and subnet address and the remaining 13 are for hosts within the subnet. A subnet means that part of the host space has been used to divide up the network into smaller networks. In this case the network address may be 16.100.0.0 /16 and the subnet uses the first 3 significant bits of the host space to split it into up to 8 subnets.

So that 13 bits means up to 2¹³-1 different IP addresses available - the last octet can take values between 0 and 255, and the second last between 134 + 0 and 134 + 31

It's maybe easier to see that in binary. The address you have there is `00010000.01100100.10000110.00000000` and valid IP addresses should be in the range `00010000.01100100.10000000.00000000` and `00010000.01100100.10011111.11111111` which makes me think you have the address of a host in the subnet - the subnet address would have all 0s for the 13 least significant bits, meaning the third octet would only have it's 3 most significant bits available ie it would have a value one of 0, 32, 64, 128,  96, 192 or 224

Comment: Okay, this I got it but in the same exercise they put : 130.180.20.0 /20 and this one is not a IP @ for a subnet, how that ?

Comment: Actually in the first one, I'd expect the third octet to take values using the 3 most significant bits only eg 128, 192, 224 - 134 uses the 22nd and 23rd bit

Comment: Ah man, I'm sorry, I'm a bit rusty on this, seems like the address in the first one is a host address in the subnet 16.100.128.0/19

Comment: And this other one would be a host in 130.180.16.0 /20

Comment: Makes me think I'm wrong and need to reread about it - I'll have to look in the morning if you don't get a better answer, as it's getting late - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork seems like it describes it well